# Problems with Overleaf?

Tags: texstudio, overleaf, chemistry, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I encountered an interesting problem where the following code executes well using Texstudio:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{chemnum}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{compound1}
    \replacecmpd{compound2}
    \replacecmpd{compund3}
    \includegraphics{overview.eps}
    \caption{Testing the chemical numbering functionalities of the chemscheme package with pdfLatex.}
    \label{scm:chemnum}
\end{scheme}

This is a reference to compound \refcmpd{compound2}.

\end{document}
```

Yielding the following pdf:
[image: pdf generated in texstudio]

However, when executing this code in Overleaf:
[image: pdf generated in overleaf]
with the following error message:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `output-pics.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Does someone have an idea on why that is happening? In both of the examples pdfLatex was used as compiler.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: texstudio and overleaf are not really involved here, are you using pdflatex (not latex) in both cases?

Comment: and is overview.eps in your overleaf project

Comment: TeXstudio is merely a front-end to a TeX distribution. Do please tell us which TeX distribution you employ (MikTeX? TeXLive? something else?) and when you last updated it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using pdflatex in both cases and overview.eps is in my project

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ksvshysntryg

Comment: @Mico Tex Live 2022 on overleaf (newest) and Tex Live 2023 natively with Texstudio.

Comment: On Overleaf, you may need to specify `\def\jobname{main}` at the start of your `main.tex` for pstricks to work with pdflatex. The example at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/using-pstricks-with-pdflatex-on-overleaf/dktntcxgyqmy might help.